# tshark gives invalid capture filter error

Tags: python, syntax-error, wireshark, tshark

I'm trying to capture packets between two hosts using a python script. The function is as follows :

```
def wire_cap(IP1,IP2,op_fold,file_name,duration):  # invoke tshark to capture traffic during session
    batcmd='"c:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe" -i 1 src ' + str(IP1) + ' or src '+ str(IP2) +' -a duration:'+str(duration)+' -P -w '+ op_fold+file_name+'.pcap'
    p = subprocess.Popen(batcmd, shell=True,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        out = p.stderr.read(1)
        if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
            break
        if out != '':
            sys.stdout.write(out)
            sys.stdout.flush()
    thread.exit()
```

However, this gives the following error :

```
Capturing on 'Local Area Connection'
tshark: Invalid capture filter "src 172.28.3.87 or src 172.28.3.56 -a duration:40 -P -w C:\Python_Scripts\wire_capture.pcap" for interface 'Local Area Connection'!

That string isn't a valid capture filter (syntax error).
See the User's Guide for a description of the capture filter syntax.
0 packets captured
```

Initially, I thought the issue was with the interface, which is passed as '1', but after checking with Wireshark, there seems to be no problem with that. I verified with the official documentation too. Every option I passed looks fine.

I'm sure I'm missing out on something here. It would be really helpful to receive any directions suggesting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tshark command is:

```
c:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe" -i 1 src 172.28.3.87 or src 172.28.3.56 -a duration:40 -P -w C:\Python_Scripts\wire_capture.pcap
```

That command mixes command-line flag arguments (the ones beginning with `-`) and capture-filter arguments.  Capture filter arguments must either come after *all* command-line flag arguments, i.e.

```
c:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe" -i 1 -a duration:40 -P -w C:\Python_Scripts\wire_capture.pcap src 172.28.3.87 or src 172.28.3.56
```

or be part of a command-line flag argument, namely a `-f` argument:

```
c:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe" -i 1 -f "src 172.28.3.87 or src 172.28.3.56" -a duration:40 -P -w C:\Python_Scripts\wire_capture.pcap
```

That's the standard convention for UN*X commands - and for Windows commands that use UN*X-style syntax (which usually means commands that originated on UN*X, as tshark did, or that are trying to maintain compatibility with UN*X commands).

So try

```
    batcmd='"c:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe" -i 1 -a duration:'+str(duration)+' -P -w '+ op_fold+file_name+'.pcap src ' + str(IP1) + ' or src '+ str(IP2)
```

Comment: Oh. That was helpful. Thanks a lot. Your answer did the job!